# Get latest Document with respect to ObjectID timestamp Mongo

Tags: mongodb, database

I am looking for the correct query that will get the latest inserted document in a mongo collection based on the ObjectID (while holds a time-stamp).

Is that a good method of getting the latest inserted document efficiency wise?

Thanks.

Comment: In Java using the MongoDB Driver:  DBCursor curgsor = coll.find().sort(new BasicDBObject("_id",-1)).limit(1);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get last document in `ObjectId` from "primary" `_id` order:

```js
db.collection.find().sort({ "_id": -1 }).limit(1);
```

Hate to burst your bubble, but that is just as how simple it is.

Point is that the "preceeding" bytes of an `ObjectId` actually come from the present "timestamp" value. Along with some other "randomness" in the overall content, this pretty much makes sure that the value as as whole is "monotonic" or "ever increasing" for its value.